# Execution failed for task ':app:splitsDiscoveryTaskDebug'

Tags: visual-studio-code, flutter

I'am trying to test flutter but I get an error when i try to build the default flutter app newly generated on visual studio code (with F5)

here is my visual studio code debug console

```
Launching lib\main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:splitsDiscoveryTaskDebug'.
> org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 45s
Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
Exited (sigterm)
```

Here is the flutter doctor

```
[√] Flutter (Channel master, v1.1.6-pre.33, on Microsoft Windows [version 10.0.17134.472], locale fr-FR)
• Flutter version 1.1.6-pre.33 at C:\flutter
• Framework revision 6502a1bed9 (3 days ago), 2019-01-05 07:34:02 -0800
• Engine revision 716185fb79
• Dart version 2.1.1 (build 2.1.1-dev.0.1 ec86471ccc)

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 28.0.3)
• Android SDK at C:\Users\dtano\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
• Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling support)
• Platform android-28, build-tools 28.0.3
• Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
• Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1136-b06)
• All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Android Studio (version 3.2)
• Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
• Flutter plugin version 31.3.1
• Dart plugin version 181.5656
• Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1136-b06)

[√] VS Code (version 1.30.1)
• VS Code at C:\Users\dtano\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
• Flutter extension version 2.21.1

[√] Connected device (1 available)
• Android SDK built for x86 • emulator-5554 • android-x86 • Android 8.0.0 (API 26) (emulator)

• No issues found!
```

I got the same issue with the stable branch of flutter

thanks for your help

Comment: does it work with Android Studio (I am seeing you already have it)?

Comment: I don't try to build it in android studio, i didn't know it was possible. I'll give it a try

Comment: I got the same error in android studio too

Comment: No one can help me ?

Comment: What happens when you go to `dev` branch?

Comment: I got the same problem after switching to a branch... Any updates?